# Get executing assembly name using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to pull the project name using the reflection, but during the substring method it give me "index out of bound error".

```
string s = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;           
int idx = s.LastIndexOf(@"\");
s = s.Substring(idx, s.Length);
```

I don't understand why it is giving error on the third line.

Plz Help.

Comment: Clarify project name. Code does not contain project names.

Comment: They've invented breakpoints a while back...

Comment: Say your path length is 15 chars, s.Length will be 15.  Substring with 2 params will accept the beginning index and the length, NOT the stop index.  So in your example, you are trying to get 15 characters from the start index, thus you get index out of bound.  If you insist on using Substring, you need to change the second param to s.Length - idx instead, otherwise, use System.IO.Path.GetFileName as suggested below.  Mind you, your method will return the \ also, so you really want idx + 1, s.Length - idx - 1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Comment: the project name is not necessarly the same as the assembly name.

Answer (score 1):

Have you debugged the code ?  Are you sure that the 2nd line returns a value other than -1 ?
When no backslash is found in the string, `LastIndexOf` will return -1, which is not a valid index that can be used by `Substring` and thus, an 'index out of bounds' error will be thrown.

A safer method would be to extract the filename using the methods that are defined in the Path class.
But, be aware that the 'project name' is not necessarly the same as the assembly name.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Path` class instead of trying to reinvent the wheel and calculating the substring indexes manually.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the second parameter from the call to Substring.
From the documentation:

```
// Exceptions:
//   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
//     startIndex plus length indicates a position not within this instance.  -or-
//     startIndex or length is less than zero.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try accessing the AssemblyTitle Attribute in your AssemblyInfo file. Location of any assembly may not be the same as the project name. Try this:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
AssemblyTitleAttribute titleAttr = (AssemblyTitleAttribute)  a.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitlenAttribute), false)[0];
Console.WriteLine("Title: " + titleAttr.Title);
```

hth