# How to get the project name when running website/web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website and a web application that both log to a common error table. I want to be able to know which project logged the error. But I cant do it with some global property. I would like to get the project name through reflection. Is this possible? Is it even kept in the manifest and will be be available no matter what symbols the projects have been built with?

Answer (score 1):

Try with below

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Ref Link::: [Get executing assembly name using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848753/get-project-name-using-reflection)

http://forums.devshed.com/net-development-87/c--get-project-s-name-via-net-object-483704.html

Answer (score 1):

"Project" is purely a VS/MSBuild concept and as such does not exist outside of realm of these tools. What I can suggest instead is to use first "segment" of a namespace of `Global.asax`-"derived" application.

```
var applicationName = typeof(Application).Namespace.SubstringBeforeFirst(".");
```

Answer (score 0):

i see two solutions (assuming your error table is SQL-based)

- dupe error table and "give" eachproject its own to write into, then if you need to aggregate them you can make up a simple union in a view (you can then have project name in the resulting table based on where the records come from)
- add a column "project name" to the error table, then fill it when you write your error (since every project knows what's his name when it writes, it's a trivial task and hardcoding this data wouldn't smell too much)

if you have restricitons, please explain what where and why so we can help more easily.